# How to align navbar so that it does not overlap logo..?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem while aligning navbar. When I resize window my navbar overlaps logo...

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bvsbkr2/)

code :

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6)">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="height:70px;">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" style="z-index: 100">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/471x71&text=MY+LOGO+GOES+HERE" style="position:fixed;"/>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Page 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Services 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services 4</a></li>                                
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>                      
                    <li><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg navbar-btn btn-secondary" style="margin:10px;margin-top: 0;border-radius: 0;">Sign in</button></li>                      
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg navbar-btn btn-secondary" style="margin:10px;margin-top: 0;border-radius: 0;">Register</button></li>
                </ul>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What is your desired style/effect? To have the logo always above? to have the logo always next to the nav-bar?

Comment: I want to have logo next to navbar...How to keep space between logo and navbar so that both does not overlap either...?

Comment: The problem you have is that as the navbar and logo are so big, apart from large desktop displays, you have a serious lack of room to sit these next to each other. Being responsive you will want to think how this should look on smaller screens where you have the lack of space.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it my giving the width to **navbar-brand** class and apply image with as 100%

**css**

```
 @media(max-width:768px){

     .navbar-brand{
         width:70% /*change the width as per your requirement*/
    }

    .navbar-brand img{
         width:100%; /* adjust the width as per your logo size*/
        position:relative!important;
    }
```

here is the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4bvsbkr2/11/)** LINK

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make it like this
Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4bvsbkr2/1/

```
@media (max-width: 1360px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

But i dont like this, because, its collapse very soon, maybe you can for each resolution different styling of elements like

```
<div class="visible-sm"></div>
<div class="visible-xs visible-sm"></div>
```